# Cause of unknown type name and undeclared identifier errors?

Tags: c++, identifier, typename

I have a header file that's linked to some others in a project of mine.  Here is all the code in the file that's giving me the error:

```
#ifndef RELATION_H_
#define RELATION_H_

#include <set>
#include <string>
#include "Scheme.h"
#include "Tuple.h"

class Relation
{
public:
    void select();
    void project();
    void rename();

private:
    std:string name;
    Scheme scheme;
    std::set<Tuple> tuples;
};

#endif /* RELATION_H_ */
```

When I compile, I get an error as follows:

```
./Relation.h:25:2: error: unknown type name 'std'
        std:string name;
        ^
./Relation.h:25:6: error: use of undeclared identifier 'string'
        std:string name;
```

I have checked for circular dependencies (the two files included here have no other files included in them) and as you can see the `<string>` class is clearly included.  No errors occur with `std::set`.  What then might be causing this problem?

Update: for good measure, I isolated this file and the five associated with it (the .cpp and the two pairs included) and compiled.  I got the same error.

Comment: I think you meant to have two colons between `std` and `string`

Comment: You're missing an additional :

Comment: Oh my goodness.  It's things like this that make me want to rethink my life.